# Difference between time complexity O(ab) and O(N^2)

Tags: time-complexity

I assume that this code ideally representation of O(n^2) complexity. The reason is `for` function in another `for` function

```
for (int i = 0; i < array. length; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) 
             System.out.println(array[i] + "," + arrayfj]);
```

Also, I read that code below is represent O(ab) time complexity. But why is that way? I don't undersant, because  `if (arrayA[i] < arrayS[j])` , this is constant and we can ignore that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) 
   for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) 
       if (arrayA[i] < arrayS[j]) 
           System.out.println(arrayA[i] + + arrayBfj]);
```

This also mentioned as O(ab), although `for (int k = 0; k < 160800; k++)`  is also as constant

```
for (int i = 0j i < arrayA.length; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++)
          for (int k = 0; k < 160800; k++) 
             System.out.println(arrayA[i] + "," + arrayB[j]);
```

Different sites write different information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first case, each array is the same length (n), and n*n prints are done.

In the second, the sizes of the arrays are a & b, and a*b ifs are done, and (potentially) that many prints are done (maybe everything in A is less than everything in B).

In the third, the sizes of the arrays are a & b, and (a*b)*160800 prints are done, but the constant can be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

I also think that the OP is missing an important point.  It's not that the first algorithm is `O(n)`.  It's that the first algorithm is `O(n)` where n is the length of the array.  Though it is usually implicit, the variables we use in big-O notation must have some relationship to the inputs to the algorithm.

Likewise, the second algorithm is `O(ab)`, where `a=length(arrayA)` and `b=length(arrayB)`.

Regarding the `if` statement.  If the `if` statement is false, then those two lines run in some small constant time.  If the `if` statement is true, then those two lines run in some slightly larger, but still small constant time.  The goal of big-Oh notation is to ignore constants, and just to see how the running time of the algorithm is related to the inputs.  So a constant is a constant is a constant.

Likewise for the third program.  The loop is run a constant number of times.  Hence it takes a constant amount of time.  A constant is a constant, even if it's large.